# Will my pthread wait or will the main thread wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So i'm getting the hang of using c/c++ but i'm still a bit misguided. I'm also trying to learn synchronization at the same time so things aren't going perfect.

So my potential problem here is,

- I have a Node object, Node has a method called run. Run creates a pthread and passes a function pointer of a function called compute() as a parameter.
- The Compute function has one parameter which is the Node that called Run()
- The Compute function will then access a Semaphore (sem_t) that is a field of the Node object passed as a parameter and will call sem_wait(Node.sem) on that semaphore.

If I do this, will the newly created thread that is running the compute function actually call the sem_wait and do the defined behavior. Or will the the process that originally created the Node call sem_wait?

Comment: This question is confusing. Whatever calls it will call it... If you do something in your thread handler then it's being done on that thread. If you do something in the main thread then its being done there. Everything happens in exactly the way you tell it to happen.

Comment: @JasonC in what way is it confusing, such that I can clarify it more?

Comment: Does my comment answer your question? If not, then add whatever you need to add to clarify why not.

Comment: @Johnathan I think the question is confusing because the answer is so obvious to most people who have used it. Whichever thread calls a function will call that function, so if the function waits then that thread will wait, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sem_wait` call will execute in the thread in which it was called (as @Jason C points out in his comment). From what you've described that happens in `run` after the thread has been started, hence `sem_wait` will be executed in the first thread.

You seem to be thinking that because the `Node` object is used in both threads that somehow has an effect on which thread will execute a call. It doesn't. Threads share memory space so your `Node` object can be used in any thread within a process. That's when you start getting into thread safety issues.

Comment: @Johnathan It looks like it. You say that `compute` is being passed as the function when starting the thread and it then calls `sem_wait`. Which means that `sem_wait` is executed in the newly created thread.

Comment: @Johnathan In the future a Miniminal, Complete, Verifiable Example will help when asking questions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  We're coders here, posting code helps.

Comment: @Johnathan The thread that calls sem_wait will execute sem_wait.